# Form POST values are not passed on submit when using iPhone

Tags: php, ios, iphone, forms, email

I have an issue with a HTML form via email.

My project sends an email to a recipient, with a link to a PHP script. The script checks for POST values, and proceeds based on these values.

This works as expected when using any browser via my laptop, however I'm running into an issue when trying to follow the link through my iPhone. Every mail app/browser I try, the POST values are not passed on submit.

The form is as follows.

```
<form method='post' action='https://fakeurl.com/recruitment/vacancy.php?jobID=$jobID&vacancyID=$vacancyID'>
    <input type='hidden' name='invitationCode' value='$stage2InvitationCode'>
    <input type='hidden' name='application' value='true'>
    <input type='hidden' name='stage' value='2'>
    <input type='submit' value='Please click this link'>
</form>
```

When tested on laptop, I get the following.

```
array(3) { 
    ["invitationCode"]=> string(40) "756bd0265fb4716858b1ec736da50c1ef3b8de18" 
    ["application"]=> string(4) "true" 
    ["stage"]=> string(1) "2" 
}
```

On iPhone.

```
array() {}
```

Any ideas? Happy to provide more information as necessary.

Comment: Try debugging the console with https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/02/remote-debugging-ios-safari-on-os-x-windows-and-linux/

Comment: Since you are using a GET and a POST at the same time, that confuses some browsers.

Comment: It's pretty much unversally agreed that including a form (especially one with hidden fields) in an email is a very bad idea. It's a security risk as users have no indication where the data is being sent and as such many mail clients will just strip it out. Use a link with query parameters, or just link to a form on your website